# Jquery template each tag: Rendering multiple select boxes using

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery-templates, jquery

I am using jquery each tag to render json data from the server as a selectbox. For eg:

```
$('#dogsBox').append(  $.toxmpl("{{each dogs}}<option value='${$value.id}'>${$value.name}</option>{{/each}}",data) 

$('#catsBox').append(  $.tmpl("{{each cats}}<option value='${$value.id}'>${$value.name}</option>{{/each}}",data)

$('wolvesBox').append(  $.tmpl("{{each wolves}}<option value='${$value.id}'>${$value.name}</option>{{/each}}",data)
```

Assuming dogs, cats and wolves are properties on another object animals, how can I make this generic? What should I substitute for the "?????" in the below script.

animals : [dogs:..., cats:...., wolves:...]

```
    for(var animalName in animals){
    $("#"+animalName).append(  $.tmpl("{{each ????? }}<option value='${$value.id}'>${$value.name}</option>{{/each}}", animals );

}
```

Leaving the parameter to each blank and passing animals[animalName]as the data doesn't work either.

Thanks,
Chris.
P.S: I am using each because it works with objects as well, and not just lists.

Comment: Any tips on how to use $item within the each tag would be helpful too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(var animalName in animals){
    $.each(animals[animalName], function(key, val){
            $("#"+animalName ).append(  $.tmpl("<option value='${id}'>${name}</option>", val)  );
        }
    );
```

Comment: As I have mentioned in the P.S, I am using each tag because it iterates on objects as well as arrays. Leaving it out is not an option for me as the input JSON data could either be an array or a object or a map and the script has to be able to iterate over any of them.

Comment: but u looping in 'for' and also u looping in 'each'. u cant do that because there is no array in each elements of 'for'

Comment: There is, animals is a collection/array which contains cats,dogs etc which are again collection/array/object.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, I am giving your answer a shot.

Comment: Sedat, your previous comment was the right answer. I cant use the recent answer as it is not generic, if there is a fish tomorrow I will have to edit the script. The basic idea is to use jquery each instead of the {{each}}. Here is the script that worked for me: for(var animalName in animal){
  $("#"+animalName ).html('<option value="">All</option>');
  $.each(animals[animalName], function(key, val){
    $("#"+animalName ).append(  $.tmpl("<option value='${id}'>${name}</option>", val)  );
   }
  ); 
    
value='${$value.id}'>${$value.name}</option>{{/each}}")  );
        
 }

Comment: Can you please revert your answer so that I can mark it as an answer.